# Images are loading much slowly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using rails 3.2, heroku and S3 from where images load at a page, where I have fifteen images, these images take about 20-25 sec to load. How to load these images fastly so that my page take less time to load?

[image]

Comment: What speed does this show on your site? http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

Comment: Perf. grad: 85/100, 
Request: 30, 
Load Time: 16.52 sec, 
Page Size: 2.0 Mb

Comment: maybe you can fix the images sizes to minimize the MB, 2.0 MB seems to be quite much to load..

Comment: This appears to be latency related. Heroku is based is using AWS in US East (Virgina datacenter).  You appear to be connecting from India. You may be able to improve performance by using cloudfront which will bring the images to a datacenter closer to your location.

Comment: I think Cloudfront is designed for asset caching, not content!

Comment: Hi @datasage , I could not find any tutorial that discribes how to intigrate cloudfront for getting content, everyone is telling about assets. Can you guide me how to intigrate cloudfront for fetching content not assets.

Comment: @AfzalMasood Its used for asset delivery. You would keep the files within s3, but instead deliver them via cloudfront. S3 is a storage system located in a single datacenter, cloudfront is a delivery system that can use s3 as an origin but with endpoints around the globe.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great tutorial to help you set up CloudFront for your Rails 4.x application:

http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/setting-up-a-cloudfront-cdn-for-rails/

In addition to the steps mentioned here, set far future expiring headers in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=31536000"
```

This works with Heroku.  If you are serving assets from S3, take a look at the AWS documentation to use CloudFront with S3:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html

I have not done this personally but it looks pretty straightforward.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the assets are coming from s3.amazonaws.com then you can remove Heroku from the equation here as the visitors browser is connecting directly to Amazon and not involving Heroku at all. I would suggest moving the assets closer and as already suggested look at Cloudfront.

For comparison, here's what I get from the UK

[image]

Comment: No, assets are not coming from s3. I am using s3 bucket only for content not for assets. Only that content taking much time to load.

Comment: all your JPGS (assets) are clearly coming from s3 in my screenshot and yours.

Comment: Yes these images(content) are coming from s3. I was using the word assets for css, js and for those images which are using in css.

Comment: ok, so now we're agreed that it's the images that are coming from S3 and they are slow for you (but significantly faster for me) - have you considered CloudFront? There isn't a magic switch to make S3 run faster aside from CloudFront.

Comment: I am little confuse, in rails assets is a seprate folder consist of css, js and images(used in css). and every tutorial of cloudfront is talking about assets/static assets not for content of page(images) then how to use cloudfront for these images.

Comment: Afzal, you are confused about what is and is not an "asset."  If you can store it in S3, it is an "asset" in the sense of CloudFront discussions.

Comment: Thanks all of you. Now I need to know, Is there any good tutorial for cloudfront according to my senario or atleast related to at some extent?